# saving an image to bytes and uploading to boto3 returning content-MD5 mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, boto3

I'm trying to pull an image from s3, quantize it/manipulate it, and then store it back into s3 without saving anything to disk (entirely in-memory). I was able to do it once, but upon returning to the code and trying it again it did not work. The code is as follows:

```
import boto3
import io
from PIL import Image

client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='',
        aws_secret_access_key='')
cur_image = client.get_object(Bucket='mybucket',Key='2016-03-19 19.15.40.jpg')['Body'].read()

loaded_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(cur_image))
quantized_image = loaded_image.quantize(colors=50)
saved_quantized_image = io.BytesIO()
quantized_image.save(saved_quantized_image,'PNG')
client.put_object(ACL='public-read',Body=saved_quantized_image,Key='testimage.png',Bucket='mybucket')
```

The error I received is:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (BadDigest) when calling the PutObject operation: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.
```

It works fine if I just pull an image, and then put it right back without manipulating it. I'm not quite sure what's going on here.

Comment: put_object() Body expect : Body (bytes or seekable file-like object) -- Object data. Can you try  saved_quantized_image.seek(0) before put_object()?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had this same problem, and the solution was to seek to the beginning of the saved in-memory file:

```
out_img = BytesIO()
image.save(out_img, img_type)
out_img.seek(0)  # Without this line it fails
self.bucket.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name,
                       Key=key,
                       Body=out_img)
```

Comment: any reason, why we need to set the file pointer to the begining?

Comment: Because the `save` function uses the pointer to iterate through the file. When it reaches the end it does not reset the pointer to the beginning, so any future operations start at the end of the file.

Answer (score 6):

The file may need to be saved and reloaded before you send it off to S3. The file pointer seek also needs to be at 0.

My problem was sending a file after reading out the first few bytes of it. Opening a file cleanly did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question getting the same error trying to upload files -- two scripts clashed, one creating, the other uploading.  My answer was to create using ".filename" then:

```
os.rename(filename.replace(".filename","filename"))
```

The upload script then needs to ignore . files.  This ensured the file was done being created.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else facing similar errors, this usually happens when content of the file gets modified during file upload, possibly due to file being modified by another process/thread.

A classic example would be to scripts modifying the same file at the same time, which throws the bad digest due to change in MD5 content. In the below example, the data file is being uploaded to s3, while it is being uploaded, if another process overwrites it, you will end up with this exception

```
random_uuid=$(uuidgen)
cat data
aws s3api put-object --acl bucket-owner-full-control --bucket $s3_bucket --key $random_uuid --body data
```