# After uploading image to s3, upload accompanying thumbnail

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I can successfully upload my images to s3 via AJAX. However I need to have an accompanying  thumbnail in my s3 bucket as well.

Here's my s3 upload ajax view:

```
...
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)
s3 = session.resource('s3')

s3.Bucket('****-bucket').put_object(Key='media/%s' % random_filename, Body=img, ContentType='image/png')
return HttpResponse()
```

What is the best way to create and upload a thumbnail from my code? Do I add another `put_object` under my current one? If so, how do I implement a thumbnail generator like PIL? I tried to replicate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274868/saving-an-image-to-bytes-and-uploading-to-boto3-returning-content-md5-mismatch) however the setup is quite different to mine.

Or is it viable to use a AWS lambda function instead?

Any advice appreciated.

EDIT:

Files can be uploaded via 2 methods: image from disk and image from URL. The filename is taken from a random string generated in my frontend.

```
def upload_image(request):
    random_filename = request.POST.get('random_filename')
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.FILES:
            for file in request.FILES:
                if file == "image":
                    img = request.FILES.get('image')

        else:
            img = request.POST.get('imageURL')
            img = img_from_url(img)


        session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        )
        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        s3.Bucket('****-bucket').put_object(Key='media/%s' % random_filename, Body=img, ContentType='image/png')
```

---

```
def img_from_url(file):
    image_data = requests.get(file).content
    return ContentFile(image_data)
```

Comment: Side-note: It is not a good idea to store credentials with the source code. Instead, run the code on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned IAM Role (which will supply credentials automatically) or create a credentials file via `aws configure`.

Comment: The credentials are seperate to the source code - in an `.env` folder outside my project files.

Answer (score 2):

Use OpenCV to resize the image and encode it to bytes, and have Boto3 upload those bytes to S3 under a new key name for the thumbnail:

```
import boto3
import cv2

BUCKET_NAME = "MY_BUCKET_NAME"

# Load original image from disk
original_image_filename = "original_image.png"
original_image = cv2.imread(original_image_filename)

# Resize the original image to obtain a thumbnail image,
# and encode this thumbnail to bytes in the PNG format
thumbnail_image = cv2.resize(original_image, (100, 100))
thumbnail_image_png = cv2.imencode(".png", thumbnail_image)[1].tostring()

# Upload the PNG bytes of the thumbnail to S3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
thumbnail_image_filename = "thumbnail.png"
object = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, thumbnail_image_filename)
object.put(Body=thumbnail_image_png, ContentType="image/png")
```

Comment: Just tried this but it's returned an error on the `resize` line. I've added the code and Traceback in my edit if you'd like to look.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the feedback! I read a bit your code and it looks like you are setting `original_image_filename` to an S3 URL, whereas `cv2.imread()` takes as argument a file path on the disk. Make sure you are setting `original_image_filename` to the file path of the original image on your disk, and try again. If you have some time, I'm also curious about how you are obtaining `img` at the top of the code block? Could you give me some more details?

Comment: No worries. Ah is there any way to do it with the S3 URL? The way my code is I can't really use the disk file name. I've added my code in my edit.

Comment: Thanks for posting the full code. It looks like you already have the bytes of the original image in `image_data`, so there is no need to read them from the disk. You can just decode them using `original_image = cv2.imdecode(image_data)` and get rid of the line with `cv2.imread()`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: Got a `TypeError: Required argument 'flags' (pos 2) not found` on the `original_image = cv2.imdecode(img)` line. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, it seems one argument is missing from the function call. According to the documentation, you need to pass a second argument to the function: `cv2.imdecode(image_data, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`.

Comment: I've decided to use an AWS Lambda function instead, which will hopefully automatically create a thumbnail in a bucket once an image is uploaded. Thankyou for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic approaches to generating thumbnails (possibly more!).

**Generate it elsewhere**

Simply upload an additional file when you upload the original. The thumbnail needs to be generated external to the system.

**Use an AWS Lambda function to generate a thumbnail**

When the image is uploaded to Amazon S3, it can generate an event that will run an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function can then create a new, resized image.

For an example, see: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

**Use an external service**

Rather than storing the thumbnail, use an external service to generate it on-the-fly. Some such services are:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)